# cut strings with multiple enddelimiter

Tags: c++, string, split, substring, standard-library

i´m trying to figure out a substring between two different characters. the string looks like:

```
channelBlock_0\d_off_mux=8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8
channelBlock_0\d_selvth=true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true
```

i want to split after the `'='` and before the first `','`

cutting after `'='` already works for me... here´s what i got:

```
std::string line;             //contains the string from above
std::string startDel = "=";
std::string endDel   = ",";

cout << line.substr(line.find(startDel)+1,line.find(endDel));
```

my output looks like this:

```
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8
true, true, true, true, true
```

how can i cut after the first ','    so my output is just

```
8
true
```

Comment: What is your question? BTW its amazing how `8` turned into `6`

Comment: Essentially this is a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c).  You just need to change the delimiter after the first read from a `=` to a `,`.

Comment: Do it the way you did it to `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking [`substring()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/), you can see that what you need is:

```
line.substr(line.find(startDel) + 1, line.find(endDel) - (line.find(startDel) + 1));
```

since the second argument of the method states:

> **len**
>
> Number of characters to include in the substring (if the string is
>   shorter, as many characters as possible are used).